# Left join in Linq to Entities

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities, left-join

I am trying to do a left join using Linq, and failing. I have tried to follow a few examples, and ended up with this (failinmg) linq query:

```
   var defaultCategories = (from cats in Db.categories
                                 join defaults in Db.payee_default_category on cats.category_id equals
                                     defaults.category_id
                                     into merged
                                 from results in merged.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                 select new {cats.category_id, cats.description}).ToList();
```

So, I need to get ALL items in my Categories table, join to a payee_default_category on Categories.category_id = Payee_Default_Category.Category_id, and return the Category_id, the Category.Description, and a boolean of if there is a record in the payee_default_category table.

However, (overlooking the fact that I am not showing if there is a matching record...) at runtime, I get an error:

"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Data.payee_default_category] DefaultIfEmpty[payee_default_category](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Data.payee_default_category])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: Can there be two defaults per category? If so, do you want two objects returned with the same category?

Comment: Also, what version of Entity Framework are you using?

Comment: A Payee can have many categories as their defaults (But the category should only be linked to a payee once). The query I am doing is, 'Give me all the categories assigned as defaults to the Payee'. As for EF version - I'm not 100% sure. How can I tell? I am using Visual Studio 2010, but .Net Framework 3.5.

Comment: Error gone. Not sure why it happened. I deleted the model, recreated it, and it's working! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the DefaultIfEmpty method is not supported in version 1 of Entity Framework, but it is supported in version 4. You may want to upgrade.

Secondly, since you're only looking for a boolean to determine whether there are any defaults, you aren't doing a real outer join so much as an "exists," and you should be able to achieve it like this:

```
var defaultCategories = 
   (from cats in Db.categories
    let defaults = Db.payee_default_category.Where(
        d => d.category_id == cats.category_id)
    select new {cats.category_id, cats.description, hasDefaults = defaults.Any()})
    .ToList();
```

Also, your Entity Framework context would ideally be set up with table mappings, which would make your query even simpler:

```
var defaultCategories = 
    (from c in Db.categories
     select new {c.category_id, c.description, 
         hasDefaults = c.payee_default_categories.Any()})
    .ToList();
```

Comment: That looks like the fix! Thanks! But now I have another issue. I had forgotten to add the foreign key constraints to my linking table. I added them, and refreshed my EF model. All looks OK, until I compile. Now I get an error: error 3007: Problem in Mapping Fragments. It seems EF is not liking my many-to-many linking table. Is this a known issue?

Comment: I recreated the EF Model from scratch, and the issue is resolved. Your solution works 100%. I have the table mappings, and that's working very well.. Thanks.